# My SQL Workbench: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, system-error

I have an issue when connecting to the database. Last week everything is running well. However, today I tried to connect again and it appeared the messages like: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60.

This connection through ssh, before I had another issue so I have changed the setting like this and going well: [enter image description here][1]

I'm using mac os, SQL version: 8.0.24.CE. I also installed the new one which is 8.0.28 but I have the same issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D88D.png

Do you know how to fix this ? is there anything need to change in the preference ?

Best regards,
Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

first tests:
1 can you ping database?
2 are you in LAN or outside your network?
3 if outside your network do you have static or dinamic IP?
4 check your router configs (if you set a dinamic IP, maybe your ISP provider changed your local IP)